# ASP.NET Different Layouts within 1 Site

Tags: asp.net, layout, master-pages

A client has an ASP.NET website with master pages and a layout directory.

What we need is 2 different layouts on the site.  Can I easily have two layouts with different master pages on the same site?

What's the best way to do that?

Comment: Do you need one master page for one set of pages and a different master page for another set of pages, or do you need 2 different master pages and some logic to choose between them for all pages on your site?  Abe's answer pretty much covers the first, but the second is possible too. See the second section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c8y19k6h.aspx

Comment: Thanks, I needed the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Setting an ASP.NET Master Page at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15228/setting-an-asp-net-master-page-at-runtime). You can set any page to use any masterpage programmatically at runtime.

Comment: That's the way I'd do it.  ASP.NET MVC also allows choice of MasterPage via an overload ViewResult Controller.View(string ViewName, string masterName, object Model)

Comment: One drawback to this approach is that if there are any ContentPlaceHolders discrepancies between the Page and MasterPage, you'll only be aware of them at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Just create two different master pages and point the corresponding aspx pages to the desired masterpage.

Example:

page1.aspx

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Master.master" Title="Content Page 1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    Main content.
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" Runat="Server" >
    Footer content.
</asp:content>
```

page2.aspx

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/secondary.master" Title="Content Page 2" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="Main" Runat="Server">
    Main content.
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="Footer" Runat="Server" >
    Footer content.
</asp:content>
```